# how to insert a rectangle with the text on the boarder in power point?

Tags: powerpoint

What I want to do is to insert a rectangle (actually I want a rounded rectangle? )

But different from normal one, I want the text to be on the boarder, I tried right click the rectangle and select format but still can't find it.

Could some body tell how to do it?

Sorry my reputation is not enough, I can't upload the picture. Just draw something like below:
Please ignore the dotted lines.

```
----  Text -------------
|                      |
|                      |
|                      |
|______________________|
```

Comment: you should ask this question on [SuperUser.Com](http://www.superuser.com)

Comment: Is it part of stackoverflow? seems I need to register a new account there. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Insert a rounded rectangle, then insert text box over the top. Set background colour of text box to slide background colour. Select the text box to move it into the position you want, then shift-click the text box so both objects are selected. Right click on either object to 'group' (or use Format-Group) to make them behave as one object.

[image]